# How to dynamically create an array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to dynamically create an array based on a range.  I have a req_count variable.  My array needs to always have the first 6 spots as `null`, and then the variable spots as `{ "sType": "title-string" }`.  For some reason, my code below doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
var aoColumns = ['null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null']

for (i=0;i<=req_count;i++){

    aoColumns.push('{ "sType": "title-string" }');

}
```

So if req_count = 5, the result should be:

```
[   
    null,   
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null, 
    null,                                   
    { "sType": "title-string" },
    { "sType": "title-string" },
    { "sType": "title-string" },
    { "sType": "title-string" },
    { "sType": "title-string" }
],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pushing strings, not objects:

Change

```
for (i=0;i<=req_count;i++){
    aoColumns.push('{ "sType": "title-string" }');
}
```

to

```
for (i=0;i<=req_count;i++){
    aoColumns.push({ "sType": "title-string" });  
}
```

---

The same goes for your initial null values.  You're pushing the string "null" instead of actual null.

Change

```
var aoColumns = ['null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null']
```

to

```
var aoColumns = [null, null, null, null, null, null];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var aoColumns = ['null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null']
```

should be

```
var aoColumns = [null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

and

```
aoColumns.push('{ "sType": "title-string" }');
```

should be

```
aoColumns.push({ "sType": "title-string" });
```

Answer (score 1):

String is not the only type in javascript ;). `'null'` should be `null` and

`aoColumns.push('{ "sType": "title-string" }');`

should be

`aoColumns.push({ "sType": "title-string" });`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from inside the push... Push real objects into it, not strings.

For example:

```
aoColumns.push({ "sType": "title-string" });
```

Instead of

```
aoColumns.push('{ "sType": "title-string" }');
```